# Why the face centered cubic is called so?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, crystals

while reading solid state physics I was just wondering why the face centered cubic is named so. is it just because that there are atoms in the center of faces/sides of the unit cell?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, "just because" is a pretty good reason since that is what it looks like. And the body centered cubic is "just because" there is an atom in the middle of the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called that simply because the unit cell has atoms centered on each face, as well as one in each corner.